# Div acts as as if inline

Tags: css

I can't work out why my Div is acting as if inline. You can see it with a blue border on the page below:

[image]

My code is something like this:

```
<div class="welcome">
    **some content**     
</div>
<div class="quote">
    hello
</div>

.welcome {
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%; 
}

.quote { 
  color: #5192BC; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #5192BC;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

I tried making `quote` a block and clearing but neither worked. I feel it may be because `welcome` is a grid but don't know the solution.

My git is [here](https://github.com/RubenCcode/MarcellaTest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit height on the `.welcome` div is causing it to act like block component with a set height of 500px.

Removing that specific height attribute will allow the 'hello' div to be positioned after your grid container.

Should look something like this:

```
.welcome {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%; 
}
```